# How to apply material light theme in App layout of angular components with angularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html

I want to apply the material light theme, i.e. white background color and black text color in **App Layout** component of angular components with the angular dart.

Comment: The app layout component doesn't apply any colors for the main content area and already has a white background with black text by default. Custom colors can be applied via css styles to any elements you place in the page. Can you ask your question more specifically?

Comment: Sry I didn't mentioned in the question. I want to change the color of the header with a white background and the black text color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header styling is just a class and you can target it in your styles.

```
material-content > .material-header {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```